# Append info to existing error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

If I have a async function with a callback inside like this:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
    return callback(err, data);
});
```

And I'd like to append or add a simple message to the existing error object (`err`) (hopefully it's an object, may be string). Whats the best way to do so? I can wrap this error inside another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
    err.myProperty = 'test';
    return callback(err, data);
});
```

Of course you can create another object and make a property "error" with the original err object.